# Error de sintaxis en Free Pascal

Tags: pascal

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa sencillo en Free Pascal pero me 2 errores de sintaxis

```
Program par_impar;
begin
 writeln
 Begin
  write ('Introducir el valor')
  IfMod2=0 then
   write ('El numero es par')
  else
   write ('El numero es impar')
 end
```

Después de eso me dice lo siguiente

```
(2,1) Fatal: Can't find unit system used by par_impar
(0) Fatal: Compilation aborted
```

Answer (score 3):

Creo que te faltan algunas cosas, acá va un código corregido:

```
Program par_impar;
var
  numero1 : Integer;

begin

  writeln('Introducir el valor');
  readln(numero1);
  if (numero1 mod 2 = 0) then writeln ('El numero es par')
  else writeln ('El numero es impar');

 end.
```

1. Hay que agregar la sección `var` donde se define el tipo de las variables.
2. Tenías mal la sentencia `If` y la operacion `mod`, ademas de puntos y comas faltantes.
3. Por último, el `end` de finalización en pascal debe finalizar con un punto.